# Unable to get the element using the text containing line break

Tags: xpath

I need to get the span element by matching its entire text which has a line break.

Below is sample HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
    <a>
        <span>fourth<br>team</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I know we can use `//span[contains(text(),'fourth')]`, but is there any way to match the entire text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using XPath, you could use [`normalize-space()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) which would take care of spaces and newlines for you:

```
//a[normalize-space(span) = 'fourthteam']
```

Or, if you'd like to locate the `span` element instead:

```
//span[normalize-space(.) = 'fourthteam']
```